# Is there any reason I should access a set of generic types in a certain way?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following:

```
public interface IFoo { }

public class Foo<T> : IFoo { ... }
```

Is there any reason I should choose to use one of these patterns over the other?

Both allow me to achieve my goal, being able to store `Foo<T>`s, and retrieve them by their `T`, but the `Type` in the dictionary method seems rather redundant, however, might the `foreach` loop in the List method be less efficient than getting from a dictionary?

```
private Dictionary<Type, IFoo> foos = new Dictionary<Type, IFoo>();

public void AddFoo<T>(Foo<T> foo)
{
    foos.Add(typeof(T), foo);
}

public Foo<T> GetFoo<T>()
{
    if(foos.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
    {
         return (Foo<T>)foos[typeof(T)]; 
    }
}
```

versus

```
private List<IFoo> foos = new List<IFoo>();

public void AddFoo<T>(Foo<T> foo)
{
    foos.Add(foo);
}

public Foo<T> GetFoo<T>()
{
    foreach(Foo foo in foos)
    {
        if(foo is Foo<T>)
        {
            return (Foo<T>)foo;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to which part you are asking about, one uses a dictionary and one uses a list. What patterns are you talking about?

Comment: @Sayse I'll edit the question to make the code's purpose more clear.

Comment: Just a suggestion, your second implementation could be re-written as `return foos.OfType<Foo<T>>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @DavidG Whoop, that's a typo.

Comment: Your question seems very broad and nothing to do with generics at all - basically what is the difference between dictionary and list? The list will allow you to have more than one object of type `T` for a start

Comment: Basically it reads like its about `Dictionary.Get` vs. `List.Find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer the first version, but I'd prefer usage of `TryGetValue` over `ContainsKey` + getter, so:

```
public Foo<T> GetFoo<T>()
{
    Foo<T> foo;
    if(foos.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out foo)
    {
         return foo;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Primarly, the dictionary is way more efficient than `O(n)` (probably around `O(log(n))` but I'm unsure), what is mainly important when you have lots of items. In the case of below of 10 entries, its probably even worse than using a list because of the overhead.

Secondarly, it's the better readable design. Whoever needs to read your code will be better able to understand what you mean.

Comment: Reasons as to why the first version is preferred would be useful.

Comment: Not to say that this is invalid, but is there a reason for picking this over the other?

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht I meant I wasn't trying to say "You're wrong!" by asking for a reason.